# When I export my model as stl file, a small part of it becomes distorted, what do i do?

Tags: modeling, mesh, export, stl, saving

When I export my model as an STL file, a small part of it becomes distorted but when I export it as OBJ it is fine. I don't know what is going wrong. I opened the STL in meshlab the problem was still there. I am a beginner. Please help me resolve this issue. The back of the ear is distorted in the second image. while in the first one it's fine.
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but without any information/screenshots of your object's geometry, possible modifiers, the export settings and not even a hint on what exactly distorted small parts could look like in your special case - like some before in Blender and afterwards as STL comparison- how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: I have added screenshots. please check now

Comment: It's still difficult to see which part is distorted, especially when the Blender viewport shading is using the metal car paint matcap instead of the standard Studio lighting setting. Also as @GordonBrinkmann says you haven't included any information about modifiers or export settings.

Comment: Pleas indicate which part of the mesh is distorted. A before-and -after  comparison in the same material would help, too.

Comment: check now please. is there anything else I should add?

Comment: On the Viewport Overlays menu (dropdown from double-circle icon on R/H side of header), check 'Face Orientation' and see if that 'missing' face is shown in red. If so you have inverted normals on that face which can cause visibility problems in external programs. Go into Edit mode, Select All, and then Shift-N to recalculate the normals. The whole object should now be blue. Then try exporting again.

Comment: it's not blue even after pressing the keys shift+N

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: I have shared it. please take a look